# Already exist? parallel computing

Tags: parallel-computing, opencl

Parallel computing allow us to compute tasks in parallel. And if there was a system like torrent that unlike sharing files, it share computing power?
For example I have a gpu and I use only 25% of its power, so the remaing 75% is used for compute tasks of others computers.

Sorry for my poor english

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE! It seems you are interested in distributed (or grid) computing such as Folding@Home (which does exactly what you are asking about; see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_distributed_computing_projects). However, this site works best for focused question with a single detailed answer that actually helps you (see http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), so you should make your question much more specific (what kind of problems are you trying to solve? what kind of resources do you have available?)

Answer (score 1):

The [BOINC](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/) project does what you describe. Some of the most famous projects using this concept are [Folding@home](https://folding.stanford.edu/) and [SETI@home](http://setiathome.berkeley.edu/).

Comment: yes, but noone use this concept to render a game for example

Comment: The latency would be far too high for such a critically real-time application.

Comment: let's say one node would run a game, then the rasterization process (for example) would be shared by all other nodes. If there are 1000 computers that use few cpu, then I think both the time to send/recive the task and the time to compute the task would be little

Comment: We are talking about workloads of 1/60 seconds here if we assume that the game should run at 60 frames per second. The overhead of sending out all the geometry information over the network, rasterizing remotely, then sending the results back in, waiting until all nodes have synced up, etc, would be quite high.